# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el nombre de un item haciendo doble foreach con php?

Tags: php, json, data

Quiero pedir una ayuda con respecto a una solicitud json por medio de php, estoy intentando obtener los datos de tipo string, mediante una dirección json por url. Actualmente estoy utilizando la api que ofrece `deezer`.

Ahora lo que pretendo hacer es obtener el nombre string de un genero musical de un album, pero solo me arroja dicho valor en entero. Cómo genero un foreach dentro de otro foreach con php.

Actualmente tengo esto y funciona solo pidiendo la información básica, mas no el string del genero.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-12');

error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

$url ="https://api.deezer.com/artist/62996/albums";
$urlGeneros = "https://api.deezer.com/genre/";

$ch = curl_init($url);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$data= curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  

$objeto = json_decode($data, true);
$items = $objeto['data'];

$registros = "[";
foreach ($items as $item){
    if ($registros != "[") {
        $registros .= ",";
    }
    $registros .= '{"idAlbum": "'.$item["id"].'",';
    $registros .= '"titleAlbum": "'.$item["title"].'",';
    $registros .= '"fansAlbum": "'.$item["fans"].'",';
    $registros .= '"publicacionAlbum": "'.$item["release_date"].'",';
    $registros .= '"tracksAlbum": "'.$item["tracklist"].'",';
    $registros .= '"idGeneroAlbum": "'.$item["genre_id"].'",';
    $registros .= '"imageAlbum": "'.$item["cover_medium"].'"}';
}
$registros .= "]";
echo $registros;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es obtener todos los géneros desde $urlGeneros y luego, dentro del bucle, obtener el valor correspondiente según el genre_id

Suponiendo que obtienes los géneros y los guardas en un array de este modo:

```
$generos = json_decode($data, true);
```

Cuando llegas a la línea del género, tendrías que buscar en cada uno de los registros de ese array el que coincide con dicho genre_id:

```
$registros .= '"idGeneroAlbum": "'.$item["genre_id"].'",';
foreach ($generos as $genero) {
    if ($genero["id"] == $item["genre_id"]) {
        $registros .= '"generoAlbum": "'.$genero["name"].'",';
        break;
    }
}
```

Lo ideal sería poder guardar el listado de géneros en un array asociativo para poder buscar por identificador de manera que lo obtuvieras algo así: `$genero[$item["genre_id"]]["name"]`

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente no sea la mas adecuada, pero he conseguido mostrar los datos por los cuales anteriormente solicitaba ayuda. Agregué otras líneas de código aunque en cuanto a tiempo de proceso se demora un poco.

El código final que tengo, ya funciona, pero es un poco largo.

```
<?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

    $url ="https://api.deezer.com/artist/62996/albums";
    $urlg = "https://api.deezer.com/genre/";

    $ch = curl_init($url);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data= curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);  
    $objeto = json_decode($data, true);
    $items = $objeto['data'];

    $chg = curl_init($urlg);   
    curl_setopt($chg, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
    curl_setopt($chg, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
    curl_setopt($chg, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $datag= curl_exec($chg); 
    curl_close($chg);  
    $objetog = json_decode($datag, true);
    $generos = $objetog['data'];


    $registros = "[";
    foreach ($items as $item){
        if ($registros != "[") {
            $registros .= ",";
        }

        $registros .= '{"idAlbum": "'.$item["id"].'",';

        $registros .= '"idGeneroAlbum": "'.$item["genre_id"].'",';
        foreach ($generos as $genero) {
            if ($genero["id"] == $item["genre_id"]) {
                $registros .= '"generoAlbum": "'.$genero[$item["genre_id"]][$genero["name"]].' ",';
                $registros.= '"generoAlbum": "'.$genero["name"].' ",';
                break;
            }
        }

        $registros .= '"titleAlbum": "'.$item["title"].'",';
        $registros .= '"fansAlbum": "'.$item["fans"].'",';
        $registros .= '"publicacionAlbum": "'.$item["release_date"].'",';
        $registros .= '"tracksAlbum": "'.$item["tracklist"].'",';
        // $registros .= '"idGeneroAlbum": "'.$item["genre_id"].'",';
        $registros .= '"imageAlbum": "'.$item["cover_medium"].'"}';
    }
    $registros .= "]";
    echo $registros;
```

?>

Comment: me parece que estas liando bastante el asunto. Estas generando un json a mano, cuando podrías generarlo todo como un array (para ir viendo como debe ser tu estructura) y luego convertirlo a json. Te plantearia que definieras $registros como un array, y mientras recorres el $items, vayas añadiendo los valores que requieras. Luego haces un json_encode($registros, true) y ya lo tienes como json.